# Meteor Blaze helper failed reactive Session set in an event

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor code does `Session.set('key','value')` in a blaze template event and said template helper uses `Session.get('key')` to find a Mongo document in order to update the UI. It is failing to update the expected value as per the `console.log(j)` below. Any idea why and how to get the expected count of jobCategory please? Thanks

```js
//client/main.js

//templte events
  'click .jobLetter': function(e){
    Session.set('jobCategory', e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerText)
    Session.set('jobLetter', e.target.innerText)
    
  }
  
//template helpers
  'jobGroups': function(){
    let groups = []
    let jobCategory = Session.get('jobCategory')
    let jobLetter = Session.get('jobLetter')

    console.log(typeof(jobCategory))  // string
    let i = Jobs.find({'category': 'Bulb'}).count()   //selector value same as in "jobCategory"
    console.log(i)              // 19
    
    console.log(jobCategory)    // Bulb
    let j = Jobs.find({'category': jobCategory}).count()
    console.log(j)              // 0  <<< why?
```

Comment: Does the String maybe contain whitespace?

Comment: I agree with Jan K.; maybe try adding `console.log(\`|${jobCategory}|\`)` to check for whitespace.

Comment: Yes. `Trim()` shows the problem which was white space in the html template file. thanks